# Is there a way to increase the API Rate limit or to bypass it altogether for GitHub?

Tags: github

I am developing a web application which needs to send a lot of HTTP requests to GitHub. After n number of successful requests, I get `HTTP 403: Forbidden` with the message `API Rate Limit Exceeded`.

Is there a way to increase the API Rate limit or to bypass it altogether for GitHub?

Comment: Isn't that limit there to prevent automated scraping of the site?

Comment: I hit the rate limit every single day - despite sending auth details. If anyone can figure out a better way to work around it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a relative solution, because the limit is still 5000 API calls per hour,
or ~80 calls per minute, which is really not that much.

I am writing a tool to compare over 350 repositories in an organization and
to find their correlations.
Ok, the tool uses python for git/github access, but I think
that is not the relevant point, here.

After some initial success, I found out that the capabilities of the GitHub API
are too limited in # of calls and also in bandwidth, if you really want to ask
the repos a lot of deep questions.

Therefore, I switched the concept, using a different approach:

Instead of doing everything with the GitHub API, I wrote a GitHub Mirror script 
that is able to mirror all of those repos in less than 15 minutes using my
parallel python script via pygit2.

Then, I wrote everything possible using the local repositories and pygit2.
This solution became faster by a factor of 100 or more, because there was neither an API nor a bandwidth bottle neck.

Of course, this did cost extra effort, because the pygit2 API is quite a bit
different from github3.py that I preferred for the GitHub solution part.

And that is actually my conclusion/advice:
The most efficient way to work with lots of Git data is:

- clone all repos you are interested in, locally
- write everything possible using pygit2, locally
- write other things, like public/private info, pull requests, access to
  wiki pages, issues etc. using the github3.py API or what you prefer.

This way, you can maximize your throughput, while your limitation is now the
quality of your program. (also non-trivial)

Comment: This could be a way but basically you are adding in a time lag of 15 minutes  to see the contents refresh in the repository. This might be an issue where real-time information about the file might be needed.

Comment: Where did you found that rate limit is 5000 request per minute? I can see only 5000 request per hour. https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications

Comment: With the advice from Jens, the throughput gets up to 5000/min (measured in 2015). Can you try if this is still so?

Comment: Have you tried GitHub's GraphQL API? You can fetch multiple repositories data in one call and potentially lower your rate limit usage, check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67631860/12397250)

Comment: No, that is new for me. Interesting, thanks! Meanwhile this topic is of minimal interest since I changed jobs :)

Answer (score 15):

In order to increase the API rate limit you might

- authenticate yourself at Github via your OAuth2 token or
- use a key/secret to [increase the unauthenticated rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v3/#increasing-the-unauthenticated-rate-limit-for-oauth-applications).

There are multiple ways of doing this:

**[Basic Auth + OAuth2Token](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-tokens)**

`curl -u <token>:x-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/user`

**[Set and Send OAuth2Token in Header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header)**

`curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com`

**[Set and Send OAuth2Token as URL Parameter](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-as-a-parameter)**

`curl https://api.github.com/?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN`

**[Set Key & Secret for Server-2-Server communication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-keysecret)**

`curl 'https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy'`

Comment: suppose I have a python script that makes a lot of github api calls. I also got a token from my github account. Now opening my git bash, I execute any of these commands and then run python script, is that so?

Comment: but this improves the rate to just 5000 requests an hour.

Comment: Adding authentication might only increase the limit to 5000 per hour. What if that is not enough.

Comment: You could add delays in your script to avoid sending more than 5000 requests per hour.

Comment: @NasifImtiazOhi did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 12):

Just make new "Personal Access Token" [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and use simple fetch method (if you are coding in JS of course :D) and replace YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with your token.

The best way to test it is to use [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTRWD.png)

```js
async function fetchGH() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/issues', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'token YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
        }
    })
    return await response.json()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same rate-limiting issues OP is describing, same as any other call to their API?

Answer (score 10):

Solution: Add authentication details or the client ID and secret (generated when you [register your application](https://github.com/settings/applications/new) on GitHub).

Found details [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) and [here](http://developer.github.com/changes/2012-10-14-rate-limit-changes/)

"If you need to make unauthenticated calls but need to use a higher rate limit associated with your OAuth application, you can send over your client ID and secret in the query string"

Comment: Important to note to only do this for server-2-server communication. Otherwise, your client secret can be exposed to the user.

Comment: Even if you include the credentials, the rate limit is 5000 per hour. What if that is not enough.

Answer (score 6):

While seems like there's still no way to increase the rate limit, GitHub now has a GraphQL API that potentially allows you to lower your API call.

Keep in mind that GitHub calculates rate limit differently between GraphQL and REST API. GraphQL API rate limit is 5000 points / hour (not 5000 calls per hour! So 1 GraphQL call can cost you more than 1 point) You can read more here: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations (TL;DR is more resource to fetch in the query = more points)

For example, if you have similar use case with Christian's answer, instead of doing multiple call to multiple endpoint

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repoA}
GET /repos/{owner}/{repoB}
```

You can just do one GraphQL call to `https://api.github.com/graphql` with this query:

```
query {
  repoA: repository(owner:"owner", name:"repoA") {
    ...
  }
  repoB: repository(owner:"owner", name:"repoB") {
    ...
  }
}
```

Depending on what's the repository queries, you can still add even more repositories on one call and still using 1 point on each call.

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest "become an archiver" https://github.com/github/site-policy/issues/56

BTW even "non-archivers" have access to public data...

All the tools are on github.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed this error during multibrnach pipeline configuration in jenkins

I had selected the source as github. After changing it to git and passing guthub repo details it worked. (have git executable path configured in jenkins and have a credential set for authentication to github)