# Cannot increase github api rate limit on docker system

Tags: docker, github, vagrant, github-api

I am using Docker on Vagrant and I pulled image from dockerhub.

The software in image is making lots of github api call inside.

I generated personel access token from github.

I tried solutions in here: [Is there a way to increase the API Rate limit or to bypass it altogether for GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394077/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-api-rate-limit-or-to-bypass-it-altogether-for-git)

However, my api rate limit is still 60. It looks like **docker system does not use my personel token.**

How to make my system use my token whenever do github api call to increase api rate limit ?

Comment: There is nothing about Docker that would affect your ability to pass credentials to a remote API. You would need to show us how you are attempting to provide your token to your containerized service.